# Simplify in sympy with custom symbols

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Suppose that I have sympy variables `x, y` and `z`

I have the expression `(x + y) (x + y) + x`

Is it possible that I am able to define `z` as `x + y` so that I can  "simplify" the expression above to `z^2 + x`?

That is, I want to use `z` wherever I can in the simplified expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `subs` as in

```
>>> var('x:z')
(x, y, z)
>>> ((x + y)*(x + y) + x).subs(x+y,z)
x + z**2
```

The `subs` routine will sometimes try to be smart about substitutions, but works best when the substitution target is a symbol (and hence unambiguous). So if you want to try the replacement `x+y->z` in a more ambiguous expression, try replacing `x->z-y`, simplify, and then resubstitute `z-y->x` to restore anything that didn't change:

```
>>> ((x*x + 2 * x * y + y * y) + x).subs(x,z-y).expand().subs(z-y,x)
x + z**2
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know subs also worked to simplify expressions to simpler variables. Do you know if I could do the same when the expression needs to be transformed a little before substitution can be made? e.g. `((x*x + 2 * x * y + y * y) + x).subs(x+y,z)` doesn't work outright, but I'd want it to work too.